# Ambiguous overload for class operator>>

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the class operator for istream (>>) and I am getting the error `Ambiguous overload for operator>>` for some reason. The operator for ostream works perfectly but istream does not.
Does someone know why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
      Person(string name="Empty", int num=0)
      :name(name), num(num){}

      friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, Person& o)
      {
        is >> o.name>> o.num;
         return is; 
      }

      friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Person& o)
      {
        return os << o.name<< " " << o.num<< endl;
      }
    private:
      string name;
      int num;

};

int main()
{   
    ifstream fajl("input.txt");

    Person a();
    fajl >> a ;
    cout << a ;

}
```

input.txt:

```
Name1 15
Name2 16
```

I get the error in line: `fajl >> a ;`

Comment: `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Person& o)`

Comment: What is the relationship between `Osaba` and `Person`?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: What is `Osoba` ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to translate the name of the class *( Osoba = Person in Serbian )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a variable declaration:

```
Person a();
```

is a *function declaration*. The correct code to declare a variable is:

```
Person a;
```

Comment: A link or explanation of "*most vexing parse*" would be nice. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: This is **not** the most vexing parse. It is simply a function declaration. See the text in the link that @Robᵩ provided.

Comment: The slightly vexing parse